# Inserting images into python app

Tags: python

I need help with inserting images into my python app.
I need some code which actually displays the picture onto the window that opens when I run the program, and allows me to place it wherever on the screen (i am guessing with coordinates).

Please don't be the guy who says this question wasn't specific enough.  Really appreciate if you answer my question well. Thanks ;)

Comment: I guess I'm that guy: your question isn't specific enough.  The answer is going to depend entirely on which UI toolkit (Tkinter, qt, wx, etc.) you're using.

Comment: uhh im using codeskulptor

Comment: Have you read the relevant documentation in the CodeSkulptor website: http://www.codeskulptor.org/docs.html#tabs-Graphics

Comment: wow i did not see that page. much thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you are using codeskulptor, you should see how to do this at the relevant page of it's [documentation](http://www.codeskulptor.org/docs.html#tabs-Graphics):
Basically, you need to first load the image:

```
image = simplegui.load_image('<url>')
```

and then once you have done that you can then draw the image:

```
canvas.draw_image(image, center_source, width_height_source, center_dest, width_height_dest[, rotation])
```